# Showing postfix settings on linux

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I wanted to see if anyone else knew the answer to this as my googlefu is failing today.

I am trying to see the configured settings on a linux/centos server running postfix for it's email usage.

I am trying to get the server configurations to see if it's relaying(99.99% sure it is) to an external server, and what the server credentials are etc so i can mirror it to another linux server.

I am currently drawing a blank as the conf files i have found and gone through seem to only have the basic configs in there and nothing that would apply to what it's using.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Based on how you're asking, I'm guessing this is not your server. Is that correct or not? If you own the server, you configured it and so would know this, but if this server belongs to someone else then you don't have the rights to poke around like this. Please edit the question to make it more clear what your relationship to this server is, and what, specifically you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The `postconf -n` command should dump out the working config.

Look for the `relayhost` setting, if it is blank or not even there then that server isn't relaying mail.